# 2007 Excel angled text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to add text to the right side in an angled format. I have a picture I uploaded to show what I'd like to accomplish:

[image: Excel Angular Image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is under the format menu. Right click -> Format -> Alignment. Then I suggest you merge the range of cells that you want so that it isnt skewed. screenshots below.

[image: Make the changes in the alignment tab of the format window]
[image: merge cells for the range you want to cover]
[image: enjoy tilting your head]

Comment: Y'all know you like my spreadsheet left over from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/640306/net-working-hours)

Comment: Vote me up for a correct answer?

Comment: One more question. How do I push this text to the end of the landscape page? Its working fine, but I need to push the angled text all the way to the right.